# How to customize jquery dialog appearance

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

many time i use the below code to show jquery dialog but i want to customize it.

```
jQuery('#dialog').load('path to my page').dialog('open');
```

suppose when i will click on the link then a small jquery dialog will open with busy image like this way. here is the screenshot.
[image]

so initially dialog will show with progress bar and after getting html data from server side then i want to increase the height & width of dialog in loop upto that level which best fit the html data inside in dialog. here bit code for that

```
$(".ui-dialog").animate({
left: (($(window).width() - 346) / 2) + 'px',
top: (($(window).height() - 305) / 2) + 'px',
height: '305px', width: '346px'
}, 200,
function () {
$("#dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles").find('#faxmain').fadeIn(2000);
$("#dialog").css({ height: '26px' });
});
```

so just guide me with sample code how to customize this line `jQuery('#dialog').load('path to my page').dialog('open');` to have my desired effect.

so guide for few steps
1) how to set busy image at the center of dialog
2) how to work with load() callback which notify me that data comes at client side
3) how to detect height & width of html data including css style sheet applied on that html

looking for guidance. thanks

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16653467/1777090)

Comment: maybe you can check about jquery theme rolller. [link](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: @PurpleDroid : u provide dead link.

Comment: @Thomas Link is working on my side. I am even able to see answer. If you can't open it, I have copied answer's content [here](http://pastebin.com/YGYeRS1J). Check that out.